# Group multiple time values per id as one time period and display each time period with SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, subquery, plotly-dash

Is there a way to solve the following problem in a SQL query?
Assume you have the following table in a Microsoft SQL server database:

```
date_time                         | tool_id
----------------------------------|-----------------
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0100000       | 4
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0200000       | 5
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0300000       | 5
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0400000       | 5
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0500000       | 7
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0600000       | 7
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0700000       | 7
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0800000       | 4
2020-02-18 12:00:00.0900000       | 4
2020-02-18 12:00:00.1000000       | 4
```

*date_time* is a datetime in chronological order and *tool_id* is an int corresponding to a certain tool which is used in a machine at that particular timestamp. The tools are used in the machine for a certain time period (e.g. tool 7 is used from '2020-02-18 12:00:00.0500000' to '2020-02-18 12:00:00.0700000').
My goal now is to eventually get a schedule for the used tools in the following format as result table:

```
tool_id | from_date_time                         | to_date_time
--------|----------------------------------------|-------------------------------
4       | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0100000            | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0100000
5       | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0200000            | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0400000
7       | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0500000            | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0700000
4       | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.0800000            | 2020-02-18 12:00:00.1000000
```

The result is supposed to be displayed in a plotly dash web app so it is supposed to be used in a Python context. Even if there is a solution for this just using SQL, might there be a better solution combining SQL and Python?

Comment: `'t_1'` isn't a valid `timestamp`. A `rowversion` is a binary value, where as that is a `varchar`. If you weren't using a `varchar`, this would simply be a `MIN` and `MAX`, however, `varchar`s don't behave the same; `'t_10'` has a **lower** value than `'t_9'`. Will your `varchar` values always be in the format `t_{int}`?

Comment: t_1, t_2 and so on are supposed to be placeholders for concrete date_time. no varchars. Sorry, i wasn't precise enough, just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "datetime" column is always in the format `t_{int}` you can use `STUFF` to remove the first 2 characters, and then convert that value to an `int`. This allows you to order them numerically, rather than lexicographically. Then you can get the `MIN` and `MAX` with a gaps and islands solution and readd the `t_` prefix:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('t_1',4),
                ('t_3',5),
                ('t_4',5),
                ('t_5',5),
                ('t_6',7),
                ('t_7',7),
                ('t_8',7),
                ('t_9',4),
                ('t_10',4),
                ('t_11',4))V(date_time,toolid)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.date_time,
           YT.toolid,
           V.time_int,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.time_int) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.toolid ORDER BY V.time_int) AS Grp
    FROM YourTable YT
         CROSS APPLY(VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(int,STUFF(date_time,1,2,''))))V(time_int))
SELECT C.toolid,
       CONCAT('t_',MIN(C.time_int)) AS From_date_time,
       CONCAT('t_',MAX(C.time_int)) AS To_date_time
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.toolid,
         C.Grp;
```

*Edit: Untested, but based on the OP's completely changed sample data this is now just a simple gaps and island problem:*

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YT.date_time,
           YT.toolid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YT.date_time) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YT.toolid ORDER BY YT.date_time) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT)
SELECT C.toolid,
       MIN(C.date_time) AS From_date_time,
       MAX(C.date_time) AS To_date_time
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.toolid,
         C.Grp;
```

Comment: Thank you so far, I just edited my question and concretized the datetime column. I am not sure if your solution holds for my concrete situation?

Comment: That really changes the data, @CodingDude .... WEll, instead you won't need to `STUFF`, but it helps if you post representative data...

Comment: This is just a simple gaps and island question now, @CodingDude .